# Is kubeadm production ready now?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm here to know about kubeadm. I'm planing to create kubernetes cluster using kubeadm on my production environment. So, I wanted to know is kubeadm production is ready to deploy in my product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially is not production ready yet, but I've been successful setting up 1.10 and later clusters with no problems.

If you want to create an HA cluster with multiple masters there's also a kubeadm guide [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/). But use it at your own risk.

Also, keep in mind if your master(s) go down your workloads will keep running, you just won't be able to make changes or schedule new pods until the master(s) comes back up.

You can also use any of the other solutions depending on your environment as pointed out in the other answer here.

Comment: The KA doc says `You should also be aware that setting up HA clusters with kubeadm is still experimental. You might encounter issues with upgrading your clusters, for example.`.

Comment: Sure, hence use it at your own risk.

Comment: how any Open Source project could be available at no cost and be production-ready at the same time? I'd say it's either impossible or just a marketing trick to increase popularity of a project

Answer (score 5):

Happy news!

It is now.We have a production release,

> we’re excited to announce that it has now graduated from beta to
>   stable and generally available (GA)!

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/12/04/production-ready-kubernetes-cluster-creation-with-kubeadm/

Answer (score 4):

**POST EDITED** in 2019 to reflect the current situation.

In 2018, According to the K8S documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#limitations).

> The cluster created here has a single master, with a single etcd database running on it. This means that if the master fails, your cluster may lose data and may need to be recreated from scratch. Adding HA support (multiple etcd servers, multiple API servers, etc) to kubeadm is still a work-in-progress.

Whereas in novembr 2019 :

> The cluster created here has a single control-plane node, with a single etcd database running on it. This means that if the control-plane node fails, your cluster may lose data and may need to be recreated from scratch.
>
> Workarounds:
>
> Regularly back up etcd. The etcd data directory configured by kubeadm is at /var/lib/etcd on the control-plane node.
>
> Use multiple control-plane nodes by completing the HA setup instead

So, kubeadm is in 2018, kubernetes was WIP and not production ready yet. For development and testing, kubeadm should be good enough. Look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/) for other solutions.

In 2019, this availability issue is fixed.